# update the table based on primary key for postgres in python

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, insert, python-3.5, psycopg2

I have around 1000 different files which i am loading using python to the postgres database. I am able to insert the csv files into the table but if the records are already loaded in the table it should update the table with the new values depending on primary key and if primary key is not present in the table it should insert.that means i need to upsert based on primary key(without specifying the column name for primary key)

The code which i have tried jast inserts the csv to the table.

```
import csv
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(user = "postgres",
                             password = "12345",
                              host = "127.0.0.1",
                              port = "5432",
                              database = "trial")
cur = conn.cursor()
f = open('/home/Documents/try.csv')
next(f)
cur.copy_from(f,'users1', sep=',', null='')
conn.commit()
```

csv file is as follows
id is the primary key(while updating should not take the column name)

1st csv inserted to the table

```
id name
1  A
2  B
```

2nd csv

```
id name
1  C
3  O
4  P
```

The final updated and inserted table should be

```
id name
1   C
2   B
3   O
4   P
```

As the 2nd csv file with id 1 has the name C so the table must be updated .

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
create table t1 (id integer,name character varying)

insert into t1
select 1,'A'
union all
select 2,'B'


create table t2 (id integer,name character varying)

insert into t2
select 1,'C'
union all
select 3,'O'
union all
select 4,'P'

SELECT * FROM t1
SELECT * FROM t2

select coalesce(t1.id,t2.id),case when t2.name is not null then t2.name else t1.name end as name
from t1
full join t2 on t2.id = t1.id
```

Result:

```
1;"C"
2;"B"
3;"O"
4;"P"
```